# Why do I get a "connot be applied to 'Closure'" Warning in my gradle script?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a hard time figuring out, why IntelliJ warns me about this part in my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

(...)

distributions {
  main {
    baseName = 'someName'
    contents {
      from { 'src/readme' }
    }
  }
}
```

shot:

[image]

I took it straight from the [gradle user guide](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) and the build seems to work ok. So, is this a false positive or should I take this serious? If so, what's the problem here and how would one check the API / code to find the expected types and so on?

Comment: Do you have the guide's `apply plugin: 'distribution'` line before this? Does your build include the src/readme file?

Comment: @Jerry101 yes, `apply plugin: 'distribution'` is a couple of lines above. I edit the question to clarify that. `src/readme` was just the online example, actually I use patterns like `*.jar`, so I guess that isn't the problem either.

Answer (score 1):

it is a false positive, but if you want to make it disappear use the following

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'
distributions.create('someNameButMain', {
    baseName = 'someName'
    contents {
      from { 'src/readme' }
    }
})
```